# Advanced segment for any pages in our shop

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to create an advanced segment to capture any visits where a category page within our shop was viewed.

Basically, I want to know which visits viewed pages WITHIN our shop.

For the shop itself, it's simply ...com/shop

but there are many categories under the shop, and they change fairly often, so I don't want to create a segment where I list out each individual page under the shop.

any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it sounds like you just need to make a segment that says

`[include] [page] [begins with] [..com/shop]`

Might have to change that `[begins with]` to `[contains]` if the `..` you listed can be different things..

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I have a segment set up that way to track visits that include/page/contains/com/shop      but now I'm trying to set up a segment to track visits where the user takes one step further into our shop by going into one of the category pages (e.g., /shop/shoes, or /shop/jewelry)